# console log dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: article.description }}

Tags: reactjs

I built a wyziwig following the instructions here: https://blog.learningdollars.com/2020/04/01/how-to-add-a-rich-text-editor-in-your-react-app-using-draft-js-and-react-draft-wysiwyg/

Now I want to add a show/hide container based on 3 lines of text in the output.

I'm just trying to `console.log(dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: output }})`, so I can test the show/hide as well as add an ellipsis. Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Edit:
If you don't want to follow the link, I have setup a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-draft-wysiwyg-fjfh9

More Details:

`<div class="modal-body" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: output }} />` comes from a library `draftjs-to-html`. It takes a string such as the following `<p>This text is <strong><em>BOLD AND ITALIC</em></strong> with this wyziwyg.</p>`, and outputs a string display to the html page such as the following...

"This text is ***BOLD AND ITALIC*** from a wyziwyg."

What I want to be able to is determine the `.length()` of the html displayed output string(above). To do this, I need to see if there is a way to `console.log(dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: output }})`;

Comment: If you are going to give a - vote, can you at least leave a comment as to why?

Comment: I think `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is not a function you can wrap `console.log` around?! Although I don't really understand your question, I didn't downvote... Can you please explain in more detail?

Comment: @JosefWittmann added more details in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to get the length to the text from a html string, you could do the following, since you assume the contents to be safe (coming from the user's editor):

```js
const getTextLength = (html) => {
  // This will never get added to the DOM.
  const element = document.createElement("div")
  element.innerHTML = html
  return element.textContent.length
}

// Some test cases.
const outputs = [
  "Some text",
  "<p>Some text</p>",
  "<p><strong>Some</strong> text</p>"
]

// Should ouput `9` for all test inputs.
console.log(outputs.map(getTextLength))
```

Comment: how would I pass the incoming `output` coming in from the props to that last line?

Comment: It's just a normal function called `getTextLength`. If you want to log the length of your ouput, just do `console.log(getTextLength(output))` somewhere in your component.